# Idle worker button in Starcraft?

Tags: starcraft

Is there an "Goto Idle Worker" function in Starcraft I, an idle worker indicator, or an idle worker count?

**Note:** Not Starcraft II, this about the 1998 game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Starcraft you can do it via a mod, but not by default ([hack/mod](http://darkztar.com/forum/showthread.php?133869-StarCraft-Oblivion-v4.0.1))

In Starcraft 2 the default is <kbd>F1</kbd>, or the icon on the bottom left of your screen.

Comment: @C. Ross thanks for the edits lol, definitely makes it look nicer.